# WS2812B individual addressable lights too slow

Tags: pi-zero, led, ws2812

I have an rpi-0-w that I use to control WS2812B strip (300 LEDs). With one strip everything is fine, but when I connect 2 more strips, obviously, update speed drops.
***Is there a way to increase the update speed?***

Comment: control each strip separately ... nothing else can be said because you did not say anything about the current update speed, the program you are using or about the LED strip

Comment: what is "too slow" ... how fast is it? how fast do you need it?

Comment: Basically I have a loop that turns all lights on in order. It has no delay function in it, but the lights are turning on too slow. Maybe there is a library in any programming language that updates them faster?